# Copying specific columns from 1 excel sheet to another using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this formula below that states it should transfer the specific columns I have for 1 worksheet to the ones I specified in the 2nd one. However, nothing is happening. Would really appreciate some help!

```
Sub copycolumns()
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Copy
airow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 1)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 1).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 2)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 3).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 3)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 4).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 4)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 5).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 5)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 6).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 6)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 11).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 25)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 12).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 26)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 13).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 27)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 14).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 28)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 16).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 19)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 17).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 7)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 18).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 9)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 19).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 13)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 20).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 14)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 23).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 15)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 24).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 16)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 25).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 10)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 26).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 11)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 27).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 12)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 29).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 31)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 30).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 17)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 31).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 22)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 32).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 23)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 33).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 18)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 33).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 32)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 38).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 24)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 42).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 29)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 44).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 30)

Subscriber.Cells(i, 46).Copy
Subscriber.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(airow, 3)

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range(“A1”).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You should choose a method to refer to Worksheets and stick with it .. altering between sheet code name and sheet tabname ... makes the code not very readable. For instance are `Sheet1` and `Worksheets("Sheet1")` the same sheet. 

... and to which sheet does `Subscriber` refer to ... I don't see a `Set` statement anywhere assigning anything to that variable. You need to provide a little more details ... plz.

Comment: (a) Note that `Worksheets(“Sheet1”)` will not usually work - you should be using `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.  (b) What do you mean by "nothing is happening"?  (c) Does stepping through the code show it going into the `For i = 2 To lastrow` loop, or does it skip over it (i.e. `lastrow` is less than 2)?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to copy column i in worksheet A to column j in worksheet B. One line can do this for you:

**to copy values only:**

```
worksheets("B").columns(j).value=worksheets("A").columns(i).value
```

**to copy everything:**

```
worksheets("A").columns(i).Copy
worksheets("B").columns(j).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```